# Recovering data from broken android phone which is sent for replacement

Tags: encryption, data-recovery, google

Sent broken android phone to Sony customer care for replacement.
I had the device encrypted with a 4 digit numeric pin. I erased it.

I found when searching on Google that data can be recovered easily from an erased android phone. But, if it has some kind of encryption turned ON, then it is a little hard to recover.

I had peace of mind that no person can look into my personal stuff and business stuff, my credit card details etc. But, today in the morning I was surprised when Google Plus notified that a photo was uploaded from the phone. Its an old phone screenshot which I took one day before 7th July, 2014 ( The day when I returned the phone ).

So, what I want to know here is, is Google photo upload got stuck somewhere for 6 days as today is 13th July, 2014 OR some person from sony staff was able to decrypt my phone? I am a little worried about my personal stuff now. Had so many accounts linked there and now I will have to log in into each google account one by one and sign out all devices.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Also, I had my LastPass account with offline login associated with that.

EDIT: Phone info as requested by @davidbaumann: Sony Xperia Z2 with latest version of Android which I think is 4.4.2 KiKat.

Comment: Cann you add information about the phone?

Comment: I voted to close (move) to SE Android as that would be the appropriate site (unless this question was in some way about how the android device works with a computer). Please do not post there, this will be moved.